# Dynamically allocated array inside a struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am learning about dynamic allocation of memory in C++. I've come across a problem for which I can't seem to find an answer.

In my program, I have a `struct` which goes like this:

```
struct Friend
{
    string name = "";
    int daysSinceContact = 0;
};

struct User
{
    string name = "";
    string password = "";
    int numberOfFriends = 0;
    Friend *friends = new Friend[numberOfFriends];
};
```

In my program, I create an array of users, which goes something like this:

```
int numberOfUsers = 5;
User *usersInformation = new User[numberOfUsers];
```

And it works fine.  But I'd like to be able to add more friends to a chosen user, for example:

```
int nFriends = usersInformation[0].numberOfFriends; 
usersInformation[0].numberOfFriends++;
usersInformation[0].friends[nFriends-1].name = "John";
usersInformation[0].friends[nFriends-1].daysSinceContact = 2;
```

I'm guessing that I should use a buffer to copy the information from the array containing information about friends, and do something like this:

```
delete[] usersInformation[0].friends[];
usersInformation[0].numberOfFriends++;
usersInformation[0].friends = new Friend[numberOfFriends];
```

And then copy it back and add information about the new friend.  But when I've tried, it didn't work.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: Change the `Friend*` to `std::vector<Friend>` and have your problems all solved

Comment: That might be true as I haven't yet read about vectors. Maybe I'm just trying to do something that I can't yet do with the tools that I have.

Comment: You can certainly do what you're describing with dynamic arrays, but it will take a lot of book-keeping on your end to make sure `new`ing, `delete`ing, and copying work correctly

Comment: The thing that I have the greatest trouble with is this part. Somehow my compiler is preventing me from doing delete[] usersInformation[0].friends[]; is this a correct way to delete this array inside an array that I already have?

Comment: Oh, I think i should just do delete[] usersinformation[0].friends

Comment: @RafałMyśliwczyk No, it isn't. Read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on the basic syntax. `delete[] usersInformation[0].friends;` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: Why have you read about new/delete, but not about std::vector? Your book isn't worth the paper it's printed on.

Comment: Thanks. I have just noticed that. But it seems i was just too blindfolded because of frustration.

Comment: I'm still in the middle of the book. Its called jumping into c++ by alex allain. The excercises are difficult but rewarding. But i do feel like its a bit weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *correct* solution is to not use a manual array at all, use the STL's [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) container instead, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Friend
{
    std::string name = "";
    int daysSinceContact = 0;
};

struct User
{
    std::string name = "";
    std::string password = "";
    std::vector<Friend> friends;
};

...

std::vector<User> usersInformation(5);

...

Friend newFriend;
newFriend.name = "John";
newFriend.daysSinceContact = 2;
usersInformation[0].friends.push_back(newFriend);

// Or simpler:
usersInformation[0].friends.emplace_back(Friend{"John", 2});
```

That being said, if you really want to manage the array manually, you need to do something more like this instead (which includes implementing the [Rule of Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) to prevent corrupting and leaking memory):

```
#include <string>

struct Friend
{
    std::string name = "";
    int daysSinceContact = 0;
};

struct User
{
    std::string name = "";
    std::string password = "";
    int numberOfFriends = 0;
    Friend *friends = new Friend[numberOfFriends];

    // default constructor (nothing extra that isn't already done above)
    User() = default;

    // copy constructor
    User(const User &src) :
        name(src.name),
        password(src.password),
        numberOfFriends(src.numberOfFriends),
        friends(new Friend[numberOfFriends])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfFriends; ++i)
            friends[i] = src.friends[i];
    }

    // move constructor
    User(User &&src) :
        name(std::move(src.name)),
        password(std::move(src.password)),
        numberOfFriends(numberOfFriends),
        friends(src.friends)
    {
        src.friends = nullptr;
        src.numberOfFriends = 0;
    }

    // destructor
    ~User()
    {
        delete[] friends;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    User& operator=(const User &src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
        {
            Friend *newFriends = new Friend[src.numberOfFriends];
            for(int i = 0; i < src.numberOfFriends; ++i)
                newFriends[i] = src.friends[i];

            name = src.name;
            password = src.password;

            delete[] friends;
            friends = newFriends;
            numberOfFriends = src.numberOfFriends;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator
    User& operator=(User &&src)
    {
        name := std::move(src.name);
        password = std::move(src.password);

        Friend *oldFriends = friends;
        friends = src.friends;
        src.friends = oldFriends;

        int oldNumber = numberOfFriends;
        numberOfFriends = src.numberOfFriends;
        src.numberOfFriends = oldNumber;

        return *this;
    }

    // addition helper
    void addFriend(const std::string &name, int daysSinceContact = 0)
    {
        Friend *newFriends = new Friend[numberOfFriends + 1];
        for(int i < 0; i < numberOfFriends; ++i)
            newFriends[i] = friends[i];

        newFriends[numberOfFriends].name = name;
        newFriends[numberOfFriends].daysSinceContact = daysSinceContact;

        delete[] friends;
        friends = newFriends;
        ++numberOfFriends;
    }
};
```

Or this, which is slightly safer in terms of memory management:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

struct Friend
{
    std::string name = "";
    int daysSinceContact = 0;
};

struct User
{
    std::string name = "";
    std::string password = "";
    int numberOfFriends = 0;
    Friend *friends = new Friend[numberOfFriends];

    // default constructor (nothing extra that isn't already done above)
    User() = default;

    // initializing constructor
    User(int initialCapacity) :
        friends(new Friend[initialCapacity])
    {
    }

    // copy constructor
    User(const User &src) :
        User(src.numberOfFriends),
        name(src.name),
        password(src.password),
        numberOfFriends(src.numberOfFriends)
    {
        std::copy(src.friends, src.friends + src.numberOfFriends, friends);
    }

    // move constructor
    User(User &&src) :
        name(std::move(src.name)),
        password(std::move(src.password)),
        numberOfFriends(0),
        friends(nullptr)
    {
        std::swap(friends, src.friends);
        std::swap(numberOfFriends, src.numberOfFriends);
    }

    // destructor
    ~User()
    {
        delete[] friends;
    }

    // copy assignment operator
    User& operator=(const User &src)
    {
        if (this != &src)
            User(src).swap(*this);

        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator
    User& operator=(User &&src)
    {
        src.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    // swap helper
    void swap(User &other)
    {
        std::swap(name, other.name);
        std::swap(password, other.password);
        std::swap(numberOfFriends, other.numberOfFriends);
        std::swap(friends, other.friends);
    }

    // addition helper
    void addFriend(const std::string &name, int daysSinceContact = 0)
    {
        User temp(numberOfFriends + 1);

        std::copy(friends, friends + numberOfFriends, temp.friends);
        temp.friends[numberOfFriends] = Friend{name, daysSinceContact};

        std::swap(friends, temp.friends);
        ++numberOfFriends;
    }
};
```

Either way, then you can do this:

```
User *usersInformation = new User[5];

...

usersInformation[0].addFriend("John", 2);

...

delete[] usersInformation;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpfull and interesting. Thank you very much for your effort! :)

Comment: Hi @RafałMyśliwczyk if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.